# regex - Find all numbers in HTML-formatted text

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to find all numbers in HTML document. 
However, I want to avoid numbers if they are part of the word, for example "o365", "high5", etc.

Here is what I tried so far, but it doesn't avoid words:

regex:

```
[\s+>][-.0-9]+
```

example html document:

```
<p ng-if="e.element != 'attachment'" ng-bind-html="::e.value" class="ng-binding ng-scope">123 Hello need 123 help with 0365 thanks</p>
```

Comment: No, parse HTML first, get plain text and use a normal regex like `-?\d*\.?\d+` or its variations.

Comment: `/(?=[^a-z])\d+(?=[^a-z])/gi`

Comment: \b[-.]?[0-9][,0-9]*(\.[,0-9]*)?\b

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple regex like this:

```
\b\d+\b
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/FfjcOm/1)**

The idea is to find digits with boundaries

Answer (score 0):

as you show a dot in your sample regexp, I assume that you are trying to get indistinctly floating point numbers and integers.  If you want to catch the sign, then there will be a first optional sign:

```
[+-]?
```

then it should come a sequence of digits (at least one):

```
[0-9][0-9]*
```

(this can be abreviated as `\d+`)
next, you can follow it optionally with a dot and another sequence of digits (this time it can be empty)

```
(\.\d*)?
```

And, as you posted, if you don't want them sticked to alphabetic input, you have to put word boundaries at both sides, so the final regex should be:

```
\b[+-]?\d+(\.\d*)?\b
```

as shown in [demo](https://regex101.com/r/CWPQoo/1).

In the demo you see three anomalous cases that deserve attention:

1. the right boundary avoids to match `+15350.16f`, so it gets only `+15350`, as the dot is a boundary but that is a number (and valid) so we must eliminate the right boundary.
2. in this case, the `+` sign acts as a nonword, so there's a word boundary in the left part, so the left boundary is good, it correctly scans.
3. In this case, due to the left boundary, we must skip the first part of the number (`e25`), but as the dot separates the fractional part, it is valid to scan `42` as a number, after the dot, that acts as a word boundary. Hmm... this seems complicated case.  We need to use some context to avoid this case.

To avoid this last case, we'll need to add some context *in front* of our number and use that context to decide if we accept or discard the number, and discard everything if we got a non empty string in that first group, we use:

```
([a-zA-Z]?)
```

so appending our regexp:

```
([a-zA-Z]?)([+-][0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?)
```

and in this case, we reject the match if we get something matched in group 1, in case group 1 is the empty string, we get the number from group 2. See [demo2](https://regex101.com/r/CWPQoo/3/).

If you look at the demo, you'll see that the case in which we have a letter stuck to *a signed number* can be considered as valid, if that is the case, we are rejecting the match because it fills the first group with the letter.  To avoid this, we will use two regular expressions _or_ed to form two alternatives... the first is the above regular expression *when there's no sign:*

```
([a-zA-Z]?)([0-9]+(\.[0-9]*)?)
```

And the second is the signed original (in this case the sign *is not optional).*

```
([+-][0-9]+(\.[0-9]*)?)
```

So, *in case we get something in group one, we reject the expression as a number, if we get something in *group 2* we got an *unsigned floating point or integer number* and if we get something in *group 4** (group 3 is the fractional part of the first alternative), *we got a signed floating point or integer number.*  The final regexp is:

```
([a-zA-Z]?)([0-9]+(\.[0-9]*)?)|([+-][0-9]+(\.[0-9]*)?)
```

See [demo3](https://regex101.com/r/CWPQoo/4)